# How do I set a fallback path/route with vueRouter if the navigation goBack ( < ) takes the user out of myb page?

Tags: vue.js, routes, frontend, vuejs3

I'm quite new with Vue, and vue-router. Right now I'm working on a page where we organize tennis matches, I have this component called **goBack**, it basically checks your browser history entries and take you back to the previous one, similar to the back-arrow in your browser. So I have this behavior which I don't like, and I don't know how to change it => if I set match, pass you the URL, if you enter and click on my goBack Comp it will take you out of my page. I want to avoid that with this logic, if your last browser history entry is not inside my page I want to redirect you to my home.
Here's the goBack component code:

```
setup(props, { attrs }) {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { t } = useI18n()

    const goBack = (): void => {
      if (attrs.onClick) return

      if (router.options.history.state.back === null) {
        router.replace('/')
      } else {
        router.back()
      }
    }

    return {
      t,
      goBack
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Thank you!